# How to sell a familiar?

Tags: blood-brothers

This question is regarding the [Blood Brothers mobile game](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobage.ww.a759.Blood_Brothers_Android&hl=en) on Android (and potentially other systems).

How do you sell a familiar?

I remember at the start-ish there was some hints about selling any 'extra stock' to make some cash, and I can also see a monetary value against each of the familiars in their stats screen, but nowhere can I find an option to sell.

My characters level is 20+, so I am well out of the tutorial section if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know for Android, but on iPhone you go to "More", then dismiss, pick which ones you want to sell and follow the rest of the instructions.

Comment: Yep, there it is... must have somehow glazed over that option the numerous times I was in that menu looking for it - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Click on the "More" button bellow the "Blood Brothers" button and then click on dismiss. This is how u can sell them for gold. If they are rare, epic, or legendary you can click on that "More" button and bazaar. This allows you to sell them to get crystals, mandrakes, heartsblood, etc.